# Can I change the api level of android without using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, api

My some android project is not support on eclipse. How can I import that project ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upgrade android sdk from command prompt as well using "**android update**" command. Follow the link below for more details:

http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you meant a project at below say api level 1.6, yes in the project use a general text editor and change the minsdk api level in the android manifest. You might also have to adjust the target sdk level upward in the maniifest